# Why is Django blocktrans working one place and not another?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, pinax

I have two Django templates (in a Pinax 0.9.x project) with text in a `blocktrans` block. One is working and the other isn't.

The one that's working looks like:

```
{% extends "site_base.html" %}

...

{% block body %}

    <h1>ABC</h1>

    <h2><em>DEF</em></h2>

    <p>
        {% blocktrans %}
        GHI
        ...
```

The one that's not working is getting a debug mode error of:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /JKL/
Invalid block tag: 'blocktrans', expected 'endblock' or 'endblock body'
```

It follows those headings by giving the following source code, with the `blocktrans` highlighted in red:

```
{% extends "site_base.html" %}
{% block head_title %}MNO{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <p>
        {% blocktrans %}
        PQR
        {% endblocktrans %}
    </p>
```

Are these two blocks of code isomorphic? If they aren't, what is the difference? What should I be doing to have paragraphs with their content working in `blocktrans` tags?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to load the [i18n](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-template-code) template tags:

```
<!-- your_template.html -->
{% load i18n %}
```