# How can I get this Django template to render?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, pinax

In [Why is Django blocktrans working one place and not another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38082128/why-is-django-blocktrans-working-one-place-and-not-another), I asked a similar question and accepted an answer after a "use i18n" response that resolved the behavior in question. Here, I am getting a TemplateSyntaxError in Pinax 0.9a1's template for seeing what a given user's followers are:

```
{% extends "microblogging/base.html" %}

{% load i18n %}
{% load avatar_tags %}
{% load account_tags %}

{% user_display other_user as other_user_display %}

{% block head_title %}{% blocktrans %}Followers of {{ other_user_display }}{% endblocktrans %}{% endblock %}
```

The error is:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /tweets/followers/ABC/
Caught KeyError while rendering: u'other_user_display'
```

If I'm reading the template correctly, the next-to-last (non-whitespace) line in the template defines `other_user_display`. `user_display()` is defined in `lib/python2.7/site-packages/pinax/apps/account/utils.py`.

What else needs to be done to make `user_display other_user` / `other_user_display` available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your `{{ other_user_display }}` variable within the blocktrans tag.
Second example from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag